# ¿Por qué un div se duplica en esta función de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando recargar el contenido del div `#mydiv` al pulsar un botón (la función esta asociada a un botón). Pero por algún motivo me duplica el contenido, y no veo dónde puede estar el problema.

```
function reloadmydiv() {
    $("#mydiv").fadeOut(1500);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#mydiv" ).load(window.location.href + " #mydiv" );
    }, 1000);

    $("#mydiv").fadeIn(1500);
}
```

Comment: @Mitzayapa puede serte de ayuda leer [He creado dos cuentas accidentalmente, ¿cómo puedo combinarlas?](/help/merging-accounts), pues la edición la hizo otro usuario con el mismo nombre que tú, por lo que entiendo que conectas con dos usuarios a la vez.

Answer (score 1):

Porque lo que estás haciendo no es recargar el contenido del div si no cargar la página completa que estás visualizando en el navegador dentro del div.

Como consecuencia se cargará la página completa dentro del div "#mydiv" y se creará dentro de éste un nuevo div.

Deberías reemplazar la url a cargar en la sentencia:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load(window.location.href + " #mydiv" );
```

Por la url del contenido del div:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load("http://<url contenido del div>");
```

Comment: Gracias por la rápida contestación , El problema que tengo es que es un tpl entero lo que tengo que cargar dentro del div (prestashop) y aparte de esto con una condición (if < de 5 unidades por ej). En este caso como lo podría integrar ? Muchas gracias de nuevo.